# CSS + Bootstrap - How to expand image to be responsive

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have an image, that I would like the right side pattern of it to be expanded until the end of the right side of container. My image has a peculiarity, such as the star below, so I cannot simply repeat it. I just want the horizonal pink part to continue. My real image does not have a color which can be gotten using background-color, I need the actual image to be responsive to the size of the container. Could anyone help me?

My fix at the moment was to use a fixed width for all parts (container, navbar, image, row) But I would love my website to be all responsive without a fixed value of width.

[image: Area to be expanded]

I have reached the final result, following the commenter's tip.

```
.OutterDiv{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}
.OutterDiv .responsiveImage{
    background-position: left top;
    background-image: url('address1');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
}

.OutterDiv .nonResponsiveImage {
    background-position: left top;
    color: #FFF !important;
    background-image: url('address2');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    width: 960px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe 2 images? One to be responsive and the other one with the pecularity placed on top of it? If you make it responsive the star would also increase it's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my answer.

```
.OutterDiv{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}
.OutterDiv .responsiveImage{
    background-position: left top;
    background-image: url('address1');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
}

.OutterDiv .nonResponsiveImage {
    background-position: left top;
    color: #FFF !important;
    background-image: url('address2');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    width: 960px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
}
```